# Singular values in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

**Suppose that $S$ is an isometry, and $T$ is an operator on a vector space V. Show that singular values of T and ST coincide.

Suppose $S$ is isometry and suppose that $T\in L(V)$ and T has singular values $ s_1,...,s_n $. By singular decomposition, there exists orthonormal basis $ (e_1,...,e_n)$ and $(f_1,...,f_n)$ of V.

Then, $ Tv = s_1 \langle v,e_n \rangle f_1 + ... + s_n \langle v,e_n \rangle f_n$
Then  $ (ST)v = s_1 \langle v,e_n \rangle S f_1 + ... + s_n \langle v,e_n \rangle S f_n$ $ = s_1 \langle v ,e_1 \rangle f_1 + ... + s_n \langle v, e_n \rangle f_n = T v $

Hence, $ Tv = ST v $ and their singular values coincide.

Please give me feedback on my answer.

Thanks in advance!

** Definition of singular values: Suppose $ T \in L(V)$. The singular values of T are the eigenvales of $ \sqrt {T^*T}$ , with each eigen value $\lambda$ repeated dim null $ \sqrt {T^*T} - \lambda I$ times**

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space?

Comment: Ah it is not given tho. So my answer is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure. Generally, singular values are only defined for Hilbert spaces, so I think we can assume that an inner product exists.  Has your book ever used the phrase "Hilbert space"?  If not, you're probably allowed to assume that the space is finite dimensional.  If not, then your proof is incomplete.

Comment: Note that in infinite-dimensional spaces, isometries are not generally surjective.  Also, why do you have $Sf_i = f_i?$

Comment: Thanks!I am using "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler. I don't think the book does not use the phrase. Do i have to make assumption that V is a finite dimensional inner produce space?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Any hints for me? Thanks a lot tho!

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could give Axler's definition of a singular value

Comment: It'll be easier if you put it in your question rather than as a comment

Comment: I did it! Please see the question again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
(ST)^*(ST) = T^*(S^*S)T
$$
Verify that $S^*S =  I$.  From there, it suffices to apply the definition.

Comment: Then I $ (ST)^* (ST) = T^*T = T^2 $. Then are we allowed to assume that T is projection operator? Thanks for your hints tho!

Comment: Why did you decide that $T^*T = T^2$???

Comment: Ahh I think I kinda got it. I just have to show what you have shown then I can do square root of $T^*T$ then apply the definition. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes. Since $\sqrt{T^*T}$ and $\sqrt{(ST)^*ST}$ are the same transformation, the singular values have to be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The answer seems so simple now but I have struggled for hours haha. Thanks a lot and you have a good day!